# accordion positioned absolute bottom is clipping top of content on mobile

Tags: jquery, overflow, accordion

I've created an accordion that needs to be positioned to the bottom of a mobile viewport.

url:  http://dev.killerbyt.es/bestpay6/

These content areas within the accordion open from th bottom but when the content is too long to fit on the screen the top of the content is missing and cannot be accessed as the content is position to the bottom of the screen. I have tried unsuccessfully to add a max-height with overflow-y scroll. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you supply the code instead of just linking?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've added to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u35o6dbx/